# nth Factorial of n 1s in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x

In what way can I improve this? Be that performance, readability, etc.
I'm thinking implementing NumPy would improve performance.

Usage: Calculate* the nth factorial of n 1s in a row.

*No need for a precise calculation. Magnitude and leading digits is enough.

Examples:

2nd factorial of 11. (11 x 9 x 7 x 5 x 3 x 1)

3rd factorial of 111. (111 x 108 x 105....)

...

````
import multiprocessing
import argparse
import datetime
import math

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.HelpFormatter,
    description="Calcs x factorial",
    usage=""
)

parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

def first_n_digits(num, n):
    return num // 10 ** (int(math.log(num, 10)) - n + 1)

def getones():
    if args.number == 1 :
        print(1)
        exit()

    num = ""
    for _ in range(0, args.number) :
        num += "".join("1")
    return int(num)

def getlog(send_end, i, threads, num):
    inc = int(num/threads)
    inc -= int(inc%args.number)
    start = num-inc*i
    
    end = num-inc*(i+1) if i < threads-1 else 0

    output = 0
    for j in range(start, end, -args.number):
        if j > 0:
            output += math.log10(j)
    
    send_end.send(output)

def main():
    num = getones()
    threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count() if getones()/multiprocessing.cpu_count() > multiprocessing.cpu_count() else 1
    jobs = []
    pipe_list = []
    for i in range(threads):
        recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=getlog, args=(send_end, i, threads, num))
        jobs.append(p)
        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()
    i = 0
    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
        i+=1
    result_list = [output.recv() for output in pipe_list]

    magnitude = int(sum(result_list))
    normalized = 10**(sum(result_list)-magnitude)
    
    fnd = str(first_n_digits(normalized, 3))
    print("{}.{}{}e{}".format(fnd[0], fnd[1], fnd[2], magnitude))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    main()
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(end-start)
```
````

Comment: When I try to run it, I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`: https://repl.it/repls/FearfulGruesomeParameters#main.py

Comment: What's the largest n you need to handle?

Comment: @superbrain This is moreso a personal project, so as high as I can make it within a reasonable amount of time lmao. The error is because it doesn't have an argument passed to it and I haven't assigned a default value yet (or any error handling) because I haven't had a need.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'd change is to not use `args` everywhere. You use the name "n" in the problem description, so I'd use that in the program as well. Reading `args` only once, to store the value in `n`.

Your `getones` function is rather lengthy and inefficient, taking O(n<sup>2</sup>) time to build the string. Although the rest of the program can't handle large n anyway, so efficiency doesn't really matter here. (And maybe the conversion to `int` takes quadratic time, not sure.)

Here's a shorter solution:

```
e = sum(map(log10, range(int('1' * n), 0, -n)))
print('%.2fe%d' % (10**(e % 1), e // 1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> n = 9
>>> from math import log10
>>> e = sum(map(log10, range(int('1' * n), 0, -n)))
>>> print('%.2fe%d' % (10**(e % 1), e // 1))
9.22e93968682
```

Comparison with yours ([at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/JealousWornKeyboardmapping#main.py)) for n=9, same result and mine's about three times as fast:

```
n = 9
yours:
9.22e93968682
0:00:11.911943
mine:
9.22e93968682
0:00:03.964518
```

We have a different result for example for n=2:

```
n = 2
yours:
1.03e4
0:00:00.011884
mine:
1.04e4
0:00:00.000085
```

The exact result is:

```
>>> math.prod(range(11, 0, -2))
10395
```

So I'd say yours isn't rounding correctly.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't done the string multiplication before, and I can definitely see how that would be more efficient. From my understanding, everything else is effectively the same as what I'm doing, just a little more condensed? (and rounding instead of truncating)

Comment: @Kadragon Yeah, I guess effectively the same, as I see sum and logarithm in yours as well. To be honest, I didn't read it fully, you kinda lost me at multiprocessing :-P

Comment: Haha, I lost myself a few times when doing it. After implementing some of your suggestions It's gone from 1m 16s to 50s on my machine. Main impact was the sum(map(log10....)))(slightly adjusted for parallelization). Doing it as a map instead of a for loop must've been more efficient. I'm going to update the code block if you want to take a look and see if they're anything I missed.